# Bash script appears to never complete

Tags: bash, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm writing a script that's supposed to set permissions on a private key file and ssh-add it, so that it's usable later:

```
echo "Setting up the private SSH key..."

if [[ $EUID > 0 ]]; then
  echo "This script needs to be run as root/sudo"
  exit 1
fi

#CmdLine Argument Parsing
for i in "$@"; do
    case $i in
        -k=*|--key=*)
        KEY="${i#*=}"
        ;;
    esac
done

if [ ! -e "$KEY" ]; then
    echo "Error: The private key file $KEY does not exist"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Private key found..."
fi

sudo chmod 600 $KEY
echo "Private key permissions set..."

exec ssh-agent bash
eval `ssh-agent -s`

echo "SSH Agent restarted..."
sudo ssh-add $KEY
echo "SSH Key added..."
echo "...done"
```

The script is being executed via : `sudo bash ./myscript.sh --key=~/.ssh/mykey-rsa` .
The script appears never to complete, the last observed echo being "Private key permissions set...".

Can anyone explain what's wrong with this script and how should I fix it to have it function as intended?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `exec ssh-agent bash` starts a new process that waits for the user input. The commands that follow this line will not be executed until `ssh-agent` process is finished.

If you want `ssh-agent bash` to execute some commands you should pass them to it's standard intput channel like this:

```
echo 'echo "hello world"' | ssh-agent bash
```

This way `ssh-agent` will execute the commands piped to it from stdin and finish. And the following commands will be executed afterwards.

**EDIT:**
@8bittree correctly noted in the comment that `exec` doesn't actually start a new process and instead replaces the current program in the current process with a new program, so the lines after this command would not be executed under any circumstances.

Comment: `exec` doesn't start a new process, it replaces the current program in the current process with a new program, in the same process. So with `exec ssh-agent bash`, the lines afterwards in the script wouldn't be executed even if the `ssh-agent` program finished.